# Replacing values in column of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    ID    Club
1   1   arsenal
2   1   chelsea
3   1   fulham
4   2   chelsea
5   2   fulham
6   3   arsenal
7   3   chelsea
8   3   fulham
```

Obviously my actual data frame is much bigger than this.

I want to replace the ID's from 1,2,3,... etc to a list that I have derived (10, 5, 7,...).
So for example I want my table to look like this:

```
    ID    Club
1   10   arsenal
2   10   chelsea
3   10   fulham
4   5   chelsea
5   5   fulham
6   7   arsenal
7   7   chelsea
8   7   fulham
```

My problems:

- the number of clubs with a certain ID. Where as I normally have 3 teams with a certain ID, you can see on line 4 & 5 that only chelsea and fulham have ID 5 (not arsenal).
- the list that I have only contains one ID each (not the required number, which could be as great as three).

Can anyone give me a hint as to how I should start going about this? I've been thinking about it for quite some time now and I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: Take a look at `?replace`: `df$ID <- replace(df$ID, new_IDs)`

Comment: You could also `merge` your data.frame with the look-up table.

Comment: I will incorporate both of your suggestions now and see what I can return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your two problems, but using `match` can give your the 2nd table:

```
tab <- c("1"=10, "2"=5, "3"=7)
df$ID <- tab[match(df$ID, names(tab))]
print(df, row.names=FALSE)
#  ID    Club
#  10 arsenal
#  10 chelsea
#  10  fulham
#   5 chelsea
#   5  fulham
#   7 arsenal
#   7 chelsea
#   7  fulham
```

Comment: Thanks luke - my problem was that I need to do this on a large scale (close to 300 values) so it would be quite lengthy to do it manually. I'll consider what you've put however and see how far I can go.

Comment: This isn't manual, it's a vector lookup.  You said you had a list right?  So that's the first line in lukeA's answer.  See [this blog post](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2014/01/25/vectorisation-is-your-best-friend-replacing-many-elements-in-a-character-vector/) for more.